# how to organize messaging database with postgresql, so that each user would have a "copy" of the conversation?

Tags: postgresql, messaging

How would I organize a PostgreSQL database so that each user would have a copy of the messages in the conversation? For example, if a user deleted a message, it **should not** be deleted for the other users in the conversation.

My general schema for messaging is to have 4 tables

1. users
2. conversations
3. conversations_users (join table)
4. messages

Something along the lines of this[image: messaging schema]

Comment: Change status of the message instead of delete?

Comment: what do you mean by the status of the message? wouldn't I have to change it for each user then?

Comment: messages have a status is_read. Add is_deleted. You actually set status is_deleted as true, but it is still readable.

Comment: I'm still confused. If I have **message #1** in **conversation A** and _Bob_ deletes **message #1**, if there is an is_deleted column set to `true`, then how can, say, Joe still see **message #1** in **conversation A**?

Comment: The original poster (op) cannot see conversations with status is_deleted. Other users can see the messages. Or you can call the status for "is_hidden_for_op" to make it more clear.

Comment: Then what about if the other user wants to delete the message also, even though it's not their own message? Something like facebook messenger.

Comment: Maybe you then can move the status "is_hidden" to the table conversations_users?